# Xilinx Ultrascale UART not found on Big Sur

Tags: macos, uart, macos-big-sur, zynq-ultrascale+

I'm trying to connect to the serial port of my Xilinx Ultrascale ZCU102 with my Macbook Pro (OS: Big Sur 11.2). The board is connected with a USB - miniUSB cable to a hub USB C connected to one of the Mac USB C ports.
With `lsusb | grep Serial` I get correctly listed both the USB adapter and sd card reader which compose the hub. However, I cannot figure out how to see data transmitted by the board through UART. I've tried with Serial Tools, but the two serial ports I can see does not show anything. Then, I've tried to list devices with `ls \dev`, but I cannot figure out what can be the device.

How can I solve?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean **Big Sur**? Where did you get `lsusb` from - it's not part of Big Sur AFAIK?

Comment: Yes, Big Sur (sorry, mispelled). I installed lsusb with brew

Comment: Normally, I would find the device name as follows. Unplug the device. `ls /dev > /tmp/a` Then plug in the device. `ls /dev > /tmp/b` Then `opendiff /tmp/{a,b}`

Comment: Do you know or can you see with a magnifying glass what chip is on your device? CP2102 or CH340 or other?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've tried also that way, but there are no differences among those files. The adapter is this one: https://www.amazon.it/Alluminio-Superspeed-memoria-Chromebook-dispositivi/dp/B075FGQ988/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_it_IT=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&crid=1ZPVNMO5HED0O&dchild=1&keywords=novoo+usb+c+hub+5+in+1&qid=1614632256&sprefix=novo%2Caps%2C176&sr=8-5

Comment: The UART interface is: CP2108 USB UART Interface (bridge IC/USB Micro-B connector)

Comment: Are you aware of this? See end. https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/forum.topic.html/cp210x_vcp_driver535willnotloadonbigsur1-ex5T

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've tryied to follow instructions in that link, however I'm still unable to see my uart. But if I connect an SD card or an USB memory to the adapter I can see its content